# Creating new column with .apply() and lambda row

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply, multiple-columns

I have a DataFrame which has 3 columns: Household income, num_adults, num_children. I want to add a new column 'Category' which depends on the values of all three of the other columns with multiple conditions for each category. Since there are more than two columns I know np.where is not suitable. Instead I want to use df.apply() and lambda row but I can't get the syntax to work. There are no errors but lots of the entries for Category are "Refused" when they should be one of the other categories. I know my code is not elegant, very new to this:

```
def FV(df):

MFV1 = df['Household income'] == 'Up to £10,399'

MFV2 = (df['Household income'] == 'From £10,400 to £15,599') & (
    ((df['num_adults'] ==1) & (df['num_children'] >1)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==2) & (df['num_children'] >1)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==3) & (df['num_children'] >0)) |
    (df['num_adults'] >3)
    )

MFV3 = (df['Household income'] == 'From £26,000 to £36,399') & (
    ((df['num_adults'] ==1) & (df['num_children'] >3)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==2) & (df['num_children'] >3)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==3) & (df['num_children'] >1)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==4) & (df['num_children'] >0)) |
    (df['num_adults'] >4)
    )

MFV4 = (df['Household income'] == 'From £36,400 to £51,999') & (
    ((df['num_adults'] ==1) & (df['num_children'] >3)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==2) & (df['num_children'] >2)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==3) & (df['num_children'] >2)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==4) & (df['num_children'] >1)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==5) & (df['num_children'] >0)) |
    (df['num_adults'] >5)
    )

PFV1 = (df['Household income'] == 'From £10,400 to £15,599') & (
    ((df['num_adults'] ==1) & (df['num_children'] <2)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==2) & (df['num_children'] <2)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==3) & (df['num_children'] ==0))
    )

PFV2 = (df['Household income'] == 'From £26,000 to £36,399') & (
    ((df['num_adults'] ==1) & (df['num_children'] >0) & (df['num_children'] <3)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==2) & (df['num_children'] <4)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==3) & (df['num_children'] <2)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==4) & (df['num_children'] ==0))
    )
    
PFV3 = (df['Household income'] == 'From £36,400 to £51,999') & (
    ((df['num_adults'] ==1) & (df['num_children'] >1) & (df['num_children'] <4)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==2) & (df['num_children'] >0) & (df['num_children'] <3)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==3) & (df['num_children'] <3)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==4) & (df['num_children'] <2)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==5) & (df['num_children'] ==0)) 
    )

LFV1 = (df['Household income'] == 'From £26,000 to £36,399') & (
    (df['num_adults'] ==1) & (df['num_children'] ==0) 
    )

LFV2 = (df['Household income'] == 'From £36,400 to £51,999') & (
    ((df['num_adults'] ==1) & (df['num_children'] <2)) |
    ((df['num_adults'] ==2) & (df['num_children'] ==0))
    )

LFV3 = df['Household income'] == '£52,000 and above'


if MFV1 | MFV2 | MFV3 | MFV4:
    return 'MFV'
elif PFV1 | PFV2 | PFV3:
    return 'PFV'
elif LFV1 | LFV2 | LFV3:
    return 'LFV'
else:
    return 'Refused'

df['Category'] = df.apply(lambda x: FV(df), axis =1)
```

Comment: with several conditions `if-elif-else`, have a look at [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), equivalent to `np.where` but more suitable in your case :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your parantheses are slightly misplaced. IIUC, for the second condition, you want rows where:

- the income is "From £10,400 to £15,599" AND any of the following is True
- (1) 1-2 adults and over 1 child; (2) 3 adults and no children; (3) Over 3 adults.

For such cases, it's also better to use `numpy.select`. Try:

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [df['Household income'] == 'Up to £10,399',
              
              df["Household income"].eq("From £10,400 to £15,599") & 
              ((df['num_adults'].isin([1,2])&(df['num_children'].gt(1))) |
               (df['num_adults'].eq(3)&(df['num_children'].gt(0))) |
               (df['num_adults'].gt(3))
               ),
              
              df["Household income"].eq("From £26,000 to £36,399") & 
              ((df['num_adults'].isin([1,2])&(df['num_children'].gt(3))) |
               (df['num_adults'].eq(3)&(df['num_children'].gt(1))) |
               (df['num_adults'].eq(4)&(df['num_children'].gt(0))) |
               (df['num_adults'].gt(4))
               ),
              
              df["Household income"].eq("From £36,400 to £51,999") & 
              ((df['num_adults'].eq(1)&(df['num_children'].gt(3))) |
               (df['num_adults'].isin([2,3])&(df['num_children'].gt(2))) |
               (df['num_adults'].eq(4)&(df['num_children'].gt(1))) |
               (df['num_adults'].eq(5)&(df['num_children'].gt(0))) |
               (df['num_adults'].gt(5))
               ),
              
              df["Household income"].eq("From £10,400 to £15,599") & 
              ((df['num_adults'].isin([1,2])&(df['num_children'].lt(2))) |
               (df['num_adults'].eq(3)&(df['num_children'].eq(0)))
               ),
              
              df["Household income"].eq("From £26,000 to £36,399") & 
              ((df['num_adults'].eq(1)&(df['num_children'].between(0,3))) |
               (df['num_adults'].eq(2)&(df['num_children'].lt(4))) |
               (df['num_adults'].eq(3)&(df['num_children'].lt(2))) |
               (df['num_adults'].eq(4)&(df['num_children'].eq(0)))
               ),
              
              df["Household income"].eq("From £36,400 to £51,999") & 
              ((df['num_adults'].eq(1)&(df['num_children'].between(1,4))) |
               (df['num_adults'].eq(2)&(df['num_children'].between(0,3))) |
               (df['num_adults'].eq(3)&(df['num_children'].lt(3))) |
               (df['num_adults'].eq(4)&(df['num_children'].lt(2))) |
               (df['num_adults'].eq(5)&(df['num_children'].eq(0)))
               ),
              
              df["Household income"].eq("From £26,000 to £36,399") & 
              (df['num_adults'].eq(1)&(df['num_children'].eq(0))),
              
              df["Household income"].eq("From £36,400 to £51,999") & 
              ((df['num_adults'].eq(1)&(df['num_children'].lt(2))) |
               (df['num_adults'].eq(2)&(df['num_children'].lt(0)))
               ),
              
              df['Household income'].eq('£52,000 and above')
              ]

choices = ["MFV", "MFV", "MFV", "MFV", "PFV", "PFV", "PFV", "LFV", "LFV", "LFV"]

df["Category"] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```